# How to close a certain thread from another thread when there are multiple instances

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to make a skype like program.  Each call has an accept thread and multiple user threads.  if there are two calls running and a user from the first call quits then I want to tell the first accept thread to stop but I want to keep the second one running.  I tried to put each accept thread into an "***ArrayList***" but when I call the "***interrupt()***" method it doesn't work even when the "***isInterrupted()***" method is true.

Comment: You'll need to show some code.  Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You don't need to 'close the thread'. You need to close its *socket*. That will cause the thread to exit, one way or another. This is just a data structure problem, no real question here to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear still a suggestion, you can go for `ExecutorService` -

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
    }
});
executorService.shutdownNow();
```

The `shutdownNow()` method of `ExecutorService` will will **attempt** (still uses interrupting) to stop all executing tasks **right away**, and skips all submitted but non-processed tasks.

You may want to look into `Interface Future<V>`too -
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: He doesn't want to 'stop all executing tasks right away'.

Comment: I metioned link for future interface too.
He could use future something like this - 
Future future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
    }
});

future.cancel(true);

Comment: I just want a way to stop the socket when there is more than one thread of the same kind running from a different thread.

Comment: you could possibly bundle all the thread of same kind and make them one executor service. So, easily you can shutdown the whole service(means all the threads running in that bundle).

Comment: I don't want to shut all of them down.  Say you have a thread named "accept" for one call.  Then you start another call and you instantiate accept again so now you have 2 threads with the same name.  How do i end the first accept thread.

Comment: @PrateekTalesara `shutdownNow()` is *irrelevant* and should be *deleted* from your answer. However `Future` is irrelevant as well. Cancelling a `Future` at best just interrupts the thread, and the OP has already stated clearly that that doesn't work.